# SignalR send message to Clients from external application

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to send a message to the clients connected to a Hub from another process? I set up LINQPad to reference my Hub project's DLL and set VS to attach debugging to the LINQPad process. My project has a HubNotification class that uses the following code:

```
dynamic clients = Hub.GetClients<MyHubClass>();
clients.SendMessage("My Message");
```

When debugging I can see this code being called, but my connected clients never get sent a message. I have verified with Fiddler that there is nothing HTTP happening when the above code runs. Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Comment: Can you show your javascipt code in web page?

Comment: There isn't any javascript code, the client is in Silverlight. However, the message is not being sent (I'm watching in Fiddler).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That call only works if you're in the same app domain. If you want to connect to the signalr service from another process/application, then you need to use a signalr client. More info here:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs